# How to differentiate between 2 of the same monitors in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors connected to my Windows 10 PC - they are the same make/model. I have speakers connected to one via its 1/8" audio jack. When I use these speakers with videoconferencing software (*e.g.* Teams), and I go to choose the audio output device, I can't tell which monitor has the connected speakers, as they both have the same name. Is there a way to change these names, so I can differentiate between the two, or use some other method to determine which is which?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Sound control panel, choose the device you want to rename and click the Properties button.  In the Properties window you can type a new name in the textbox.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks much.